# Correct way to create one index with two columns in Timescaledb

Tags: indexing, timescaledb

I use porstgreSQL extension called Timescaledb.i have a table called `timestampdb`.I want to ask if this is the right way to create one index with two columns(timestamp1,id13).
Some of my queries that i use look like this:

```
select * from timestampdb where timestamp1 >='2020-01-01 00:05:00' and timestamp1<='2020-01-02 00:05:00' and id13>'5',
select date_trunc('hour',timestamp1) as hour,avg(id13) from timestampdb where timestamp1 >='2020-01-01 00:05:00' and timestamp1<='2020-01-02 00:05:00' group by hour order by hour ,
select date_trunc('hour',timestamp1) as hour,max(id13) from timestampdb where timestamp1<='2020-01-01 00:05:00' group by hour order by hour desc limit 5
```

After creating the table i do this:

```
create_hypertable("timestampdb",timestamp1) and then CREATE INDEX ON timestampdb (timestamp1,id13)
```

Is this the proper way?Will this create one index with two columns?Or one index in timestamp1 and one index for(timestamp1,id13)

Comment: [CREATE INDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createindex.html) in PostgreSQL creates one index with all columns, which were included in the statement, and in the order they are provided. I suggest to read [best practivce of using composite index in TimescaleDB](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/use-composite-indexes-to-speed-up-time-series-queries-sql-8ca2df6b3aaa/)

Comment: @k_rus Thank you for your answer.I have read this multiple times but i cant find any solution to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is the proper way. The provided call will actually create an index combined with those two columns. You want to make sure that the dominant index column (ie the first) is the time-column. Which it is in your code. That way tsdb queries still find your data first by time (which is pretty important on large data sets). And your queries match that index too: they primarily search time-range-based.

You might want to check the way postgres executes your queries by executing
EXPLAIN ANALYZE ;
Or use pgadmin and click the “explain”-button.
By that you can make sure that your Indizes are hit and whether postgres has enough heap buffer to cache the tsdb table pages or needs to read from disk (which is slower by effectively a factor of 1000 to 10000).

I always find those resources helpful:
TSDB YT Channel: https://youtube.com/c/TimescaleDB
TSDB Slack Channel: https://slack.timescale.com/